# How do I change gnome icon per application?

Tags: gtk, icons, gnome

I want to change icons to something different per application. I want to change only nm-applet (gnomes network manager applet) and my volume applet to something different than the icon set. How can I do this?

Comment: This should be on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own icon theme with just those two icons in it. The other icons will be taken from the default 'hicolor' theme.